# Why does memcpy to int not work after calling memcpy to bool value

Tags: c++

I was playing around with memcpy when I stumbled on a strange result, where a memcpy that is called on the same pointer of memory after bool memcpy gives unexpected result.

I created a simple test struct that has a bunch of different type variables. I cast the struct into unsigned char pointer and then using memcpy I copy data from that pointer into separate variables. I tried playing around the offset of memcpy and shifting the int memcpy before bool (changed the layout of test struct so that the int would go before the bool too). Suprisingly the shifting fixed the problem.

```cpp
// Simple struct containing 3 floats
struct vector
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

// My test struct
struct test2
{
    float a;
    vector b;
    bool c;
    int d;
};

int main()
{
    // I create my structure on the heap here and assign values
    test2* test2ptr = new test2();
    test2ptr->a = 50;
    test2ptr->b.x = 100;
    test2ptr->b.y = 101;
    test2ptr->b.z = 102;
    test2ptr->c = true;
    test2ptr->d = 5;

    // Then turn the struct into an array of single bytes
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)test2ptr;
    // Variable for keeping track of the offset
    unsigned int offset = 0;

    // Variables that I want the memory copied into they
    float a;
    vector b;
    bool c;
    int d;

    // I copy the memory here in the same order as it is defined in the struct
    std::memcpy(&a, data, sizeof(float));
    // Add the copied data size in bytes to the offset
    offset += sizeof(float);

    std::memcpy(&b, data + offset, sizeof(vector));
    offset += sizeof(vector);

    std::memcpy(&c, data + offset, sizeof(bool));
    offset += sizeof(bool);

    // It all works until here the results are the same as the ones I assigned
    // however the int value becomes 83886080 instead of 5
    // moving this above the bool memcpy (and moving the variable in the struct too) fixes the problem
    std::memcpy(&d, data + offset, sizeof(int));
    offset += sizeof(int);

    return 0;
}
```

So I expected the value of d to be 5 however it becomes 83886080 which I presume is just random uninitialized memory.

Comment: `struct` fields are not always tightly packed. There might be padding between them.

Comment: You can use offsetof (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) to get the correct offsets of the fields of your structs.

Comment: I compared the final offset that I got from manually adding the sizeof and the offset of adding offsetoff and the difference was 21(sizeof) to 40(offsetof), how come is there a 19 byte gap here?

Comment: All of this "navigating around structs with pointers" has undefined behaviour. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was just experimenting with memcpy, and was planning to use it for creating a runtime created "struct" that can be used for setting values in DirectX shader constant buffer

Comment: You're making the mistake of treating a C++ program like assembly. It isn't. Don't work with C++ in this manner!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it wouldn't be undefined if he got the offsets right. You are allowed to memcpy between objects of the same standard-layout type

Comment: @Gytautas: You don't *add* `offsetof`, each offsetof result is measured from the beginning of the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ignore the padding of your data in a struct.

Take a look on the following simplified example:

```
struct X
{
    bool b;
    int i;
}; 

int main()
{
    X x;
    std::cout << "Address of b " << (void*)(&x.b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of i " << (void*)(&x.i) << std::endl;
}
```

This results on my PC with:

> Address of b 0x7ffce023f548
>
> Address of i 0x7ffce023f54c

As you see, the `bool` value in the struct takes 4 bytes here even it uses less for its content. The compiler must add padding bytes to the struct to make it possible the cpu can access the data directly. If you have the data arranged linear as written in your code, the compiler have to generate assembly instructions on all access to align the data later which slows down your program a lot.

You can force the compiler to do that by adding `pragma pack` or something similar with your compiler. All the `pragma` things are compiler specific!

For your program, you have to use the address if the data for the `memcpy` and not the size of the data element before the element you want to access as this ignore padding bytes.

If I add a `pragma pack(1)` before my program, the output is:

> Address of b 0x7ffd16c79cfb
>
> Address of i 0x7ffd16c79cfc

As you can see, there are no longer padding bytes between the bool and the int. But the code which will access i later will be very large and slow! So avoid use of `#pragma pack` at all!

Answer (score 1):

You've got the answer you need so I'll not get into detail. I just made an extraction function with logging to make it easier to follow what's happening.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Simple struct containing 3 floats
struct vector {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

// My test struct
struct test2 {
    float a;
    vector b;
    bool c;
    int d;
};

template<typename T>
void extract(T& dest, unsigned char* data, size_t& offset) {
    std::uintptr_t dp = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(data + offset);
    size_t align_overstep = dp % alignof(T);

    std::cout << "sizeof " << sizeof(T) << " alignof " << alignof(T) << " data "
              << dp << " mod " << align_overstep << "\n";

    if(align_overstep) {
        size_t missing = alignof(T) - align_overstep;
        std::cout << "misaligned - adding " << missing << " to align it again\n";
        offset += missing;
    }
    std::memcpy(&dest, data + offset, sizeof(dest));
    offset += sizeof(dest);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    // I create my structure on the heap here and assign values
    test2* test2ptr = new test2();
    test2ptr->a = 50;
    test2ptr->b.x = 100;
    test2ptr->b.y = 101;
    test2ptr->b.z = 102;
    test2ptr->c = true;
    test2ptr->d = 5;

    // Then turn the struct into an array of single bytes
    unsigned char* data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(test2ptr);
    // Variable for keeping track of the offset
    size_t offset = 0;

    // Variables that I want the memory copied into they
    float a;
    vector b;
    bool c;
    int d;

    // I copy the memory here in the same order as it is defined in the struct
    extract(a, data, offset);
    std::cout << "a " << a << "\n";

    extract(b, data, offset);
    std::cout << "b.x " << b.x << "\n";
    std::cout << "b.y " << b.y << "\n";
    std::cout << "b.z " << b.z << "\n";

    extract(c, data, offset);
    std::cout << "c " << c << "\n";

    extract(d, data, offset);
    std::cout << "d " << d << "\n";

    std::cout << offset << "\n";

    delete test2ptr;
}
```

Possible output

```
sizeof 4 alignof 4 data 12840560 mod 0
a 50
sizeof 12 alignof 4 data 12840564 mod 0
b.x 100
b.y 101
b.z 102
sizeof 1 alignof 1 data 12840576 mod 0
c true
sizeof 4 alignof 4 data 12840577 mod 1
misaligned - adding 3 to align it again
d 5
24
```

Answer (score 0):

There are apparently three padding bytes between the `bool` and the subsequent `int`. This is allowed by the standard due to alignment considerations (accessing a 4 byte int that is not aligned on a 4 byte boundary may be slow or crash on some systems).

So when you do `offset += sizeof(bool)`, you are not incrementing enough. The `int` follows 4 bytes after, not 1. The result is that the `5` is not the first byte you read but the last one - you are reading three padding bytes plus the first one from `test2ptr->d` into `d`. And it is no coincidence that `83886080 = 2^24 * 5` (the padding bytes were apparently all zeros).

Comment: That's not what `2^24` is in C and C++.  Why don't you just be accurate and say `0x05000000` ?